Variable only changes inside OnTriggerEnter
I'm trying to change the Health variable using the OnTriggerEnter function. This works, but only inside the function. Everywhere else it stays the same.
    using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyInteractions : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int Health;
    public void Start()
    {
        Health = 10;
    }
    public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider player)
    {
        if (player.gameObject.tag == "Enemy")
        {
            print("HIT");
            Health -= 1; // won't change outside function
            Debug.Log(Health);
        }
    }
}

I tried various ways, from using another variable to take the Health variable on itself and using any other ways I could find, but it doesn't work. The     Debug.Log(Health);     does show the correct numbers though, so it does change, but apperently only in the function itself.

so the inspector on the item doesnt show health changing?

To answer it simply, yes.

then it suggests you're looking at a different instance of the component

So how would you fix this?

You need to be looking at the right instance - with the information you have provided all I can tell you is there is anotgher instance, it is working hence the messagers and the health on it will be changing, add a gameobject to the debug log and you will find out which one
